# Revealing elements one by one in a table

Tags: tables, beamer, overlays

I want to colour elements one by one. In my example i want to colour only 3 in blue first and not 3,0. How can this be done?

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} 
        \toprule
        \diagbox{Player 1}{Player 2} & Left (L)~~ & Right (R)~ ~  \\ 
        \hline
        Up (U)                       & \color<2->{blue}{3},0        & 0,-4          \\ 
        \hline
        Down (D)                     & 2,4        & -1,8          \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Entirely unrelated to the question itself, but please be aware that the horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package such as `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` were desigened to be used without vertical lines. Hence the small white gaps around the intersections that you get.

Answer (score 1):

Using  `{\color<2->{blue}{3}},0` should result in the expected output:

[image]

Since lines from the `booktabs` package are incompatible with vertical lines, I also included two alternative table layouts in the final MWE:

[image]

[image]

Full code for all three examples:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%%%%% Packages needed for the first example table %%%%%
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{diagbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%% Packages needed for the seconf and third example table %%%%%
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\usepackage{multirow}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} 
        \toprule
        \diagbox{Player 1}{Player 2} & Left (L)~~ & Right (R)~ ~  \\ 
        \hline
        Up (U)                       &  {\color<2->{blue}{3}},0        & 0,-4          \\ 
        \hline
        Down (D)                     & 2,4        & -1,8          \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{0c0r *{2}{>{$}wr{0.75cm}<{$}@{,}>{$}wl{0.75cm}<{$}}} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}         & \multicolumn{4}{0c}{Player 2}\\
        &                              & \multicolumn{2}{0c}{Left (L)} & \multicolumn{2}{0c}{Right (R)} \\ 
        \multirow{2.75}{*}{Player 1} & Up (U)                       & \color<2->{blue}{3} & 0      & 0  &-4          \\ 
        & Down (D)                     & 2 & 4                        & -1 & 8          \\

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|0c|0r| *{2}{>{$}wr{0.75cm}<{$}@{,}>{$}wl{0.75cm}<{$}|}} 
    \cline{3-6}
     \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                                 & \multicolumn{4}{0c|}{Player 2}\\
    \cline{3-6}
     \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}             & \multicolumn{2}{0c|}{Left (L)} & \multicolumn{2}{0c|}{Right (R)} \\ 
    \hline
        \multirow{2.75}{*}{Player 1} & Up (U)                       & \color<2->{blue}{3} & 0      & 0  &-4          \\ 
    \cline{2-6}
        & Down (D)                     & 2 & 4                        & -1 & 8          \\
    \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats awesome. Thanks